# regex replace comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
var name = 'John, Doe';
```

this name could be represented like this too:

```
var name = 'john , doe';
```

or

```
var name = 'john ,doe';
```

or even

```
var name = 'john    ,   doe';
```

In all occurances, I'd like to make the name end up like this:

```
var name = 'john*doe';
```

I've violated the DRY principles already, by doing something like this:

```
name= name.replace(' ,', '*');
name= name.replace(', ', '*');
name = name.replace(',', '*');
```

and this doesn't even taken into account extra white space. Is there a regex pattern I can apply to take care of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`\s` whitespace character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) [repeated multiple times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
name = name.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, '*');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this following?

```
name = name.replace(/\s*,\s*/, '*');
```

@Bergi's answer also adds the `g` flag to catch all commas (with whitespace), so depending on your input, that may work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
name = name.replace(/[ ]*,[ ]*/, '*');
```

*I've put space in [] for clarity.*

Please note that regex in JavaScript need `/` around it. The pattern matches 0 or 1 space then the comma then 0 or 1 space.

---

If there can be tabs also use `\s` instead of a space. The `\s` will match any kind of space. So :

```
name = name.replace(/\s*,\s*/, '*');
```

Comment: What about tabs? Use `\s` instead. Also `?` will match either 0 or 1 occurences

Comment: @Zeta I just noticed that the question got edited while I first answered.